# variable value and its address using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having some trouble understanding pointers. In the following code, I'm trying print the address of a variable in 2 ways-once using the address operator and then using pointers:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int *int_pointer;
    int_pointer = &x;
    cout << "x address=" << &x << endl;
    cout << "x address w pointer=" << int_pointer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
x address = 0028FCC4
x address w pointer = 0028FCC4
```

This works as expected. But when I do the same thing but now using character type variable, I get some trash output:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    char c = 'Q';
    char *char_pointer;
    char_pointer = &c;
    cout << "address using address operator=" << &c << endl;
    cout << "address pointed by pointer=" << char_pointer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
address using address operator=Q╠╠╠╠£åbªp é
address pointed by pointer=Q╠╠╠╠£åbªp é
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ library overloads the << operator for certain types. (char*) is one of them. Cout is trying to print a string, an array of characters terminated by a null character.

Just cast the pointer:

```
cout << "address pointed by pointer" << ( void* )char_pointer << endl;
```

or

```
cout << "address pointed by pointer" << static_cast<void*>(char_pointer) << endl;
```

Comment: This is correct but I add one clarification. The C++ library overloads the << operator for certain types. (char*) is one of them. One of the bad things of C/C++ is that they have treated pointers/arrays and arrays or char/string as synonymous. The (char*) version of the << operator things you are trying to print a string, not the pointer value. When you print pointers, the best approach is to cast them to void: reinterpret_cast<void*>(point).

Comment: @user3344003 Feel free to edit my answer if you have a correction or a reasonable suggestion that would improve it, or add you answer, instead of using comments for that.

Comment: WIll do. I did not want to add another answer when this was correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints out junky stuff is because your char does not have a null terminator which means the program will keep searching for one until, and in the process will print out whatever it finds. The text you see is ASCII but referenced by the address which the ostream is misinterpreting. To get the address held in memory, you could use implicit conversion or a static_cast. I prefer the latter:

```
cout << "address pointed by pointer=" << static_Cast<void*>(char_pointer) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like 2501 said, in different wording, `&c`, since c is a `char`, equals a `char *`, so it's going to try to print until the new line character `'\0'` that is either implicitly or explicitly put in character arrays going to `std::cout` so the stream knows where the end of the character array is.

So, yeah use the (void *) like 2501 said.